# Winapi: The proper way to clear DrawText()

Tags: winapi, text, drawtext, gdi

Hi I want to clear out the `DrawText()` and I don't know how to do it properly. I could simply `SetTextColor` to the color of my background but this is not elegant way to do it I think. I dont know maybe I could do something with a rectangle `rc` that holds my text.
I draw by `case WM_PAINT` and in it:

```
hdc=BeginPaint(hwnd, &paint);
.... //some other code here
DrawText(hdc, TEXT("some text"), -1, &rc, DT_SINGLELINE);
....//some other code here
EndPaint(hwnd, &paint);
```

and one more thing. I don't have `DeleteDC(hdc);` or `ReleaseDC(hdc);` in my `WM_PAINT` is that ok, or I should have them after or before  `EndPaint(hwnd, &paint);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to "clear" text that you've drawn other than to draw something else over the top. If your background is a solid color then just draw a rectangle of that color (you can work out how big it needs to be by using the `DT_CALCRECT` flag with `DrawText`). If your background is an image then you need to blit the appropriate area of the image.

Note that drawing the text over the top of itself using the background color (as you suggest) may not work because of ClearType/anti-aliasing.

To answer your second question, no - the DC returned by `BeginPaint` is effectively deleted by the call to `EndPaint` and so you don't need to (and mustn't) delete it separately.

Comment: Thank you for your info. After I've set a user `int flag=0` or `=1` it worked perfectly :) I also have to `InvalidateRect()` after flag change its state because previous text field was still on the screen.